# Windows 8 Start Screen Lagging

Tags: windows-8, performance, scrolling, start-screen

For some reason, when explorer.exe gets restarted on my Windows 8 PC, the start screen is laggy. What I mean by laggy is that when I scroll in the start screen, it takes a bit to show the rest of the screen and it is choppy instead of smooth. I know that this usually happens when it's loaded for the first time since a reboot but for me it happens every time and not just the first. If I do a reboot of Windows, then it doesn't lag at all. Here's my specifications:

- Windows 8 Pro x64 (with latest updates)
- 6 GB RAM
- Intel Core i7 CPU 950 @ 3.07GHz
- Desktop PC
- My Graphics card is a GeForce 9600 GT and the version I have is from 2/9/2013 (but I am going to update them to the latest which is 3/14/2013)

Any ideas?

Comment: which gpu do you use? Do you use the latest drivers?

Comment: See the updated question for GPU details